# Why does Beanshell choke on the '@' characters in source files?

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, beanshell

When interpreting a .java source file,  in this case a JUnit test suite with the following declaration in it:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MiamiAForm.class })
```

Why does Beanshell (version 1.3 and also 2.1b5) choke on those characters?

```
Evaluation Error: Sourced file: com\co\tests\TestSuite.java 
Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 16, column 10.  
Encountered: "B" (66), after : "@": <at unknown location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because beanshell does not parse the syntax for some java 1.5 features. See [Issue 24:  Support of java 1.5 lang features (generics, enum, annotations)](http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/issues/detail?id=24), still open. Generics are now (partially) supported, but enums and annotations are not.

So it seems like it's not possible to run JUnit 4 tests under beanshell. Try Groovy, if you really don't want to compile them.